# In Apache POI Adding a new paragraph at a specified place while iterating is giving Concurrent Modification Exception

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, apache-poi-4, concurrentmodificationexception

Following is the code which is while iterating adding a new paragraph before a specific paragraph.

```
    public void resolveBodyElements1(List<IBodyElement> elements) {
    for(IBodyElement element : elements) {
        if(PARAGRAPH.equalsIgnoreCase(element.getElementType().name())) {
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)element;
            if(paragraph.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("[{multiline-bulletpoints-markdown}]")) {
                XmlCursor paragraphCursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
                XWPFParagraph paragraph1 = paragraph.getDocument().insertNewParagraph(paragraphCursor);
                paragraph1.createRun().setText("This is a test paragraph inserted.");

            }
            System.out.println(paragraph.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

But it ends up in a ConcurrentModification Exception, However, I am using a for loop instead of an iterator or a foreach loop. Can anyone please guide me in this regard to add a paragraph in a document while iterating the paragraphs and avoid this ConcurrentModification Exception?

Comment: `for(IBodyElement element : elements)` uses an iterator internally. Maybe create a copy of `elements` to iterate over? I assume `elements` is a mutable reference to internals, which gets changed when you call `insertNewParagraph()`.

Comment: @Kayaman I didn't get what you mean by creating a copy of elements. Is it possible for you to provide some code snippet for this?

Comment: Create a new list containing the contents of `elements`. Then iterate through the list you created.

Comment: @Kayaman Many thanks, your suggestion works. One thing I would like to ask `XWPFParagraph paragraph = this.paragraph.getDocument().insertNewParagraph(paragraphCursor);` this line is not working for a table paragraph. `this.paragraph` is a valid XWPFTable Cell's paragraph but upon executing the line for a table it is returning null. Can you please guide me in this regard?

Comment: I haven't touched POI in a while, so I can't really help.